# How to use comparison operators with dictionary values?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a task that stores the dictionary values in variable based on the condition .

I'm new to this technology. Please anyone help on the below request.

I tried with the below code. Please check below.

```
- set_fact:
      v1: "{{ v1|default([]) + item.keys() if item.values() == false else 1 }}"
    loop: "{{ dv }}"
```

'dv' is a dictionary.

```
[{1A:True},{2A:True},{3A:False},{4A:False}]
```

Actually, here I'm trying to store false values in v1 by using comparison operators only.

Expected output:

v1 should contain following list:

```
[3A,4A]
```

**Ansible Version: 2.5.15**

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    dv: [{1A:True},{2A:True},{3A:False},{4A:False}]
    v2: []
    v1: []
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        v1: "{{ v1|default([]) }} + [ {{ v1.append((item.keys()|first).split(':')[0]) if (item.keys()|first).split(':')[1] == 'False' else v2.append('1') }} ]"
      with_items: "{{ dv }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ v1 }}"
```

Here v2 is a variable declared to direct if the conditions are not met.

Output of the a above code is a below:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "3A",
        "4A"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Sriram,

It is failing with below error.

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 1

**Could you please check**

Comment: @sushmithai I have updated with full code. I think you have missed to declare and instantiate v2.

Comment: Just took the entire code in one test yaml. It is throwing below error.

**ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unexpected ':'
The offending line appears to be:

  vars:
    dv: [{1A:True},{2A:True},{3A:False},{4A:False}]
            ^ here
**

Comment: @sushmithai Indentation and spacing is important. If you have copy pasted the code then, try typing all the code. This could solve the above error.

Comment: The above one is resolved but still getting the same error as I mentioned earlier.

**The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 1**

I think error is pointing **@if (item.keys()|first).split(':')[1] == 'False' **

Comment: Try declaring and instantiating v1: [] in vars (below v2: [])

Comment: Still didn't work for me.
I'm confused, why it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dv:
      1A: 'True'
      2A: 'False'
      3A: 'True'
      4A: 'False'
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ dv | dict2items }}"

    - set_fact:
        v1: "{{ v1| default([]) + item.key if (item.value in 'False') else('') }}"
      loop: "{{ dv | dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        var: v1
```

output -->

```
TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'1A', 'value': u'True'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'3A', 'value': u'True'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'2A', 'value': u'False'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'4A', 'value': u'False'})

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "v1": "2A4A"
}
```

Comment: Hi ,
dict2items filter doesn't support.
Please suggest any other.

Comment: dict2items is in ansible version 2.6. what is your version ?

Comment: Using ansible 2.5.15 .

Comment: Please suggest any other filter other than dict2items.